# Meteor - Radio Button Group on multiple records only one selection

Tags: meteor, html-table, each

What I have is a meteor apps that uses a table to dispay information from my objects.  I am using the spacebars {{#each}} to run through the objects and dispay the table lines.  This all works great except when it comes to displaying radio buttons.  It seems to think that all of them are part of one big group and only allows one to be selected and not one per table row.

I have tried a few different things but to no avail to get each row  to be independent of the other.

Any ideas on how to handle radio buttons in meteor using {{#each}} in the template.  Pic below of the problem.

[image]

```
<td>
                        <input class="form-control box-size clearForm" type="text" name="orderChargeDescription" placeholder="Charges"  />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="orderWaChargeAddSub" value="ADD" checked>C
                        <input type="radio" name="orderWaChargeAddSub" value="SUB">U
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit"  name="orderDispUp"  class="btn btn-warning button-height-lp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        <button type="submit"  name="orderDispDn"  class="btn btn-danger button-height-lp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </td>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your template code.

Comment: I updated the question with the code snippet from around the same spot I have the picture.

Comment: The problem is that you are using the same name for each group of radio buttons, the solution is change the name in each group. I updated my answer.

Comment: So this is a radio button issue only then correct. As things like check boxes work fine. So I basically need to dynamically create group names as it is running through the #each lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a helper in the js file of the template for check if the current value is equals from the current element of the radio button array and check it:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
    isChecked: function(currentValue, value) {
        return currentValue === value ? 'checked' : '';
    } 
});
```

And in your template you could use the helper for check or not the radio button:

```
<template name="hello">
  <td>
    {{#each exampleData}}
      <input {{isChecked exampleDataItem this}} value="{{this}}" name="orderWaChargeAddSub{{this}}" type="radio">
    {{/each}}
  </td>
</template>
```

The problem that you are having is that you are using the same name for grouping the radio buttons , you have to use different name for each group of radio buttons. ex :

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control box-size clearForm" type="text" name="orderChargeDescription" placeholder="Charges"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="ADD" checked>C
                    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="SUB">U
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit"  name="orderDispUp"  class="btn btn-warning button-height-lp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <button type="submit"  name="orderDispDn"  class="btn btn-danger button-height-lp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control box-size clearForm" type="text" name="orderChargeDescription" placeholder="Charges"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="ADD" checked>C
                    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="SUB">U
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit"  name="orderDispUp"  class="btn btn-warning button-height-lp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <button type="submit"  name="orderDispDn"  class="btn btn-danger button-height-lp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </td>
             </tr>
```

Comment: This helped clear things up for me, in my object I created a stop number and applied that stop number to the end of the name of the radio button group.  This worked.  Thank you for your help.